# PHP MySQL limits query results when in WHILE loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weird problem where `mysql_`  limits results from a query, but only when it's in a while loop & adding `ORDER BY listing_name ASC`. Here's an example:

```
$listings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listings");
$listingcount = mysql_num_rows($listings);
```

`$listingcount` returns **157** rows in the listings table.

And here's what happens in the while loop.

```
$listings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listings ORDER BY listing_name ASC");
while($listingresult = mysql_fetch_assoc($listings)){
//grab some data from the query using $listingresult
//e.g: $somedata = $listingresult['listing_name'];
echo "some data here:". $somedata;
}
```

This only echos **97** rows. None of the values in `listing_name` are NULL, empty etc they all contain & start with letters.

What am I missing here? *It doesn't seem right*

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Is it sufficient to just upgrade to `mysqli_` (procedural way)?

Comment: As long as you use prepared statements, yes.

Comment: I'd still like to work out a solution to my problem however. Is there anything blatantly obvious here? (aside from `mysql_` functions, it shouldn't make a difference with regards to the simple query, should it?)

Comment: Nothing that you've shared here would help us to help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Aside from a database connection this is everything. What else could I share?

Comment: I don't know that there is anything you can share. Without being able to query the database ourselves it would be nearly impossible for us to guess at the issue. Perhaps you could create a SQLFiddle with your database, but even at that we would not be able to run code against it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard In this specific query would you agree he wouldn't need to do a prepared statement? (assuming he isn't doing this query more than once, and seeing that he isn't using user output)

Comment: You're right @Webeng, but for consistency sake if you're going to do one as a prepared statement, do them all that way.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Completely agree, and I might even recommend making a function that receives an sql statement and an array for the parameters that need binding, since repetitive code is one of the killers of beautiful code